# Change boolean to True from model to lines - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I have this method:

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('order_lines', 'order_lines.is_book_block', '')
@api.constrains('order_lines', 'order_lines.isbn')
def check_quantity(self):
    location = self.printer_book_block.property_stock_supplier.id
    for rec in self:
        if rec.order_lines:
            for line in rec.order_lines:
                if line.qty > line.isbn.with_context({ 'location': location, }).qty_available >= 0:#line.isbn.qty_available in location:
                    rec.write({'state': 'awaitingraw'})
                else:
                    rec.write({'state': 'work_in_progress',},{'is_book_block': True})
```

What it does, is to look unto `order_lines` for product quantity on a specified location, which is doing just right, but also, besides writing the form state to `work_in_progress`, but also, it should change the `order_lines` field `is_book_block` to `True`. (If there is enough product quantity on specified location)

The quantity part is OK, but as I've added the boolean part,

It throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 583, in dispatch
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 319, in _call_function
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\service\model.py", line 118, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 316, in checked_call
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 812, in __call__
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 944, in call_kw
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 936, in _call_kw
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 268, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 399, in old_api
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5989, in onchange
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\models.py", line 5832, in _onchange_eval
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\openerp\addons\bsi\models\models.py", line 1360, in check_quantity
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170914\server\.\openerp\api.py", line 266, in wrapper
TypeError: write() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Any ideas?

I think that it is because of the `onchange` decorator, but shouldn't be that the case? I mean, the product isn't always available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write accept a dicionary only one

```
   rec.write({
        'state': 'work_in_progress',
         'is_book_block': True,
         # you can put as many field as you want but inside this dicionary
  })
```

Comment: Thank You very much, it's somehow resolved, I think I'm gonna open a new question tho, I wonder, shoudln't be better to write this with some  reference to order_lines? I mean, 'state' is on the parent model, but is_book_block isn't, it is actually on the child model... and it's not changing